# Clear buffer/user data before doing another write on a Linux device driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to code a simple linux device driver that puts numbers in a linked list. Instead of use `copy_from_user`, I'm using `strcpy` to copy the buffer and add to list. This part works perfectly. But, somehow, if I add a number with less digits than the previous one, the buffer comes filled with the final digits of the previous number.

For example, if I put: 1234 and then 11, 11 comes to buffer 1134, with the last digits of the previous write.

Here's the code, a modification of an example of device driver that can be found on internet.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/aio.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/device.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Zhiyi Huang");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A template module");

int major=0;
module_param(major, int, S_IRUGO);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(major, "device major number");

#define MAX_DSIZE   3071
struct my_dev {
    char data[MAX_DSIZE+1];
    size_t size;              
    struct semaphore sem;
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct class *class;
    struct device *device;
} *temp_dev;

struct struct_list {
    int numero;
    struct list_head membro_lista;
};

LIST_HEAD(head) ;

int temp_open (struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    return 0;
}

int temp_release (struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    return 0;
}

char parsed_nums[300];

const char * display(void) {
    struct list_head *iter;
    struct struct_list *objPtr;
    char num[10];
    parsed_nums[0] = '\0';

    list_for_each(iter, &head) {
        objPtr = list_entry(iter, struct struct_list, membro_lista);
        //printk("Elem: %d", objPtr->numero);
        sprintf(num,"%d ",objPtr->numero);
        strcat(parsed_nums, num);
    }
    strcat(parsed_nums, "\n");
    //printk("%s", parsed_nums);
    return parsed_nums;
}

ssize_t temp_read (struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count,loff_t *f_pos) {
    //char* parsed_nums = display();
    display();
    printk("%s", parsed_nums);
    int rv=0;

    if (down_interruptible (&temp_dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    if (*f_pos > MAX_DSIZE) 
        goto wrap_up;     
    if (*f_pos + count > MAX_DSIZE)
        count = MAX_DSIZE - *f_pos;
    if (copy_to_user (buf, temp_dev->data+*f_pos, count)) {
        rv = -EFAULT;
        goto wrap_up;
    }
    up (&temp_dev->sem);
    *f_pos += count;
    return count;
  wrap_up:
    up (&temp_dev->sem);
    return rv;
}

void todo_add_entry(int arg) {
    struct struct_list *fooPtr = (struct struct_list *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct struct_list), GFP_KERNEL);
    fooPtr->numero = arg;

    struct list_head *ptr;
    struct struct_list *entry;
    list_for_each(ptr, &head) {
        entry = list_entry(ptr, struct struct_list, membro_lista);
        if (entry->numero >= fooPtr->numero) {
            list_add_tail(&fooPtr->membro_lista, ptr);
            return;
        }
    }
    list_add_tail(&fooPtr->membro_lista, &head);
}

ssize_t temp_write (struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    count = 0;
    int count1=count,rv=count;
    int valor;
    printk("AAA: %s", buf);
    kstrtoint(buf, 10, &valor);

    todo_add_entry(valor);
    display();

    if (down_interruptible (&temp_dev->sem))
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    if (*f_pos > MAX_DSIZE)
        goto wrap_up;
    if (*f_pos + count > MAX_DSIZE)
        count1 = MAX_DSIZE - *f_pos;
    if (strcpy(temp_dev->data, parsed_nums)) {
        goto wrap_up;
    }
    up (&temp_dev->sem);
    *f_pos += count1;
    return count;
  wrap_up:
    up (&temp_dev->sem);
    return rv;
}

struct file_operations temp_fops = {
    .owner =     THIS_MODULE,
    .read =      temp_read,
    .write =     temp_write,
    .open =      temp_open,
    .release =   temp_release,
};

LIST_HEAD(listaDupla) ;

int __init temp_init_module(void){
    int rv;
    dev_t devno = MKDEV(major, 0);

    if(major) {
        rv = register_chrdev_region(devno, 1, "temp");
        if(rv < 0){
            printk(KERN_WARNING "Can't use the major number %d; try atomatic allocation...\n", major);
            rv = alloc_chrdev_region(&devno, 0, 1, "temp");
            major = MAJOR(devno);
        }
    }
    else {
        rv = alloc_chrdev_region(&devno, 0, 1, "temp");
        major = MAJOR(devno);
    }

    if(rv < 0) return rv;
    temp_dev = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    if(temp_dev == NULL){
        rv = -ENOMEM;
        unregister_chrdev_region(devno, 1);
        return rv;
    }
    memset(temp_dev, 0, sizeof(struct my_dev));
    cdev_init(&temp_dev->cdev, &temp_fops);
    temp_dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    temp_dev->size = MAX_DSIZE;
    sema_init (&temp_dev->sem, 1);
    rv = cdev_add (&temp_dev->cdev, devno, 1);
    if (rv) printk(KERN_WARNING "Error %d adding device temp", rv);
    temp_dev->class = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "temp");
    if(IS_ERR(temp_dev->class)) {
        cdev_del(&temp_dev->cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(devno, 1);
        printk(KERN_WARNING "%s: can't create udev class\n", "temp");
        rv = -ENOMEM;
        return rv;
    }
    temp_dev->device = device_create(temp_dev->class, NULL,
                    MKDEV(major, 0), "%s", "temp");
    if(IS_ERR(temp_dev->device)){
        class_destroy(temp_dev->class);
        cdev_del(&temp_dev->cdev);
        unregister_chrdev_region(devno, 1);
        printk(KERN_WARNING "%s: can't create udev device\n", "temp");
        rv = -ENOMEM;
        return rv;
    }

    printk(KERN_WARNING "Hello world from Template Module\n");
    printk(KERN_WARNING "temp device MAJOR is %d, dev addr: %lx\n", major, (unsigned long)temp_dev);

  return 0;
}

void __exit temp_exit_module(void){
    device_destroy(temp_dev->class, MKDEV(major, 0));
    class_destroy(temp_dev->class);
    cdev_del(&temp_dev->cdev); 
    kfree(temp_dev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(MKDEV(major, 0), 1);
    printk(KERN_WARNING "Good bye from Template Module\n");
}

module_init(temp_init_module);
module_exit(temp_exit_module);
```

What could be causing this? Can anybody give me a suggestion?

Comment: Why the `if()` in? `if (strcpy(temp_dev->data, parsed_nums))`?  It is always true.  Should `temp_dev->data == NULL`, the result in_undefined behavior_.

Comment: Well noted. I will improve that.

Comment: Never use `strcat`, `strcpy`, etc if you don't know what they are exactly doing... They are quite dangerous in kernel programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you write each time on the same buffer thus you have your garbage value at the end.

To solve your problem you should add a `'\0'` after your write. Thus when you read your buffer you won't read the garbage.

If your data can contain `\0`, your best option is to store the size of your buffer in a variable and use only this amount of data.

You could also bzero your buffer each time but that would be really inefficient.

Comment: I put a `'\0'` in a buffer copy in  `size_t count` position, cutting the garbage. And it works. Thanks a lot.